# Using SQL to join two columns in one list and remove replicats

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and having an issue constructing a SQL query that joins the State and Zipcode in one column and list them without containing any duplicate records and should be sorted in descending alphabetical order.
[image: Table Address]

Comment: SELECT  state + ' ' + zipcode as StateZipCode
FROM Address
         ORDER BY State DEsC

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the 2 fields the way you want (or by using + operator or by using concat function). Then `order by` that field that you created (or by wrapping with another select and just `order by "field_name"` or as I did in the example by the position of the column in the select:

```
select distinct state + ' ' + zipcode 
from addresses 
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

if there isn't any duplicate value in your table you can use

```
SELECT concat(State, ZipCode) from Address ORDER BY state desc
```

if there is duplicate record you have to use distinct to get unique record

```
SELECT distinct concat(State, ZipCode) from Address ORDER BY state desc
```

Comment: Both queries don't work, "invalid object name 'address'"

Comment: check table name you have posted Address *invalid object name means you have written wrong TableName  @M.lob